# How does lastInsertId() work for tables without auto-incremented fields?

Tags: php, mysql

How does `lastInsertId()` work for tables that do not have an auto-incremented field?  What about tables where the primary key is made up of 2 fields?

(I'm working with MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases above it will return `0`.

When using an auto_increment column, it will return the last INSERT ID even if it was specified (i.e. the auto increment was not used).

That is to say you should only use `lastInsertId` when using auto increment.  It doesn't really make sense to use it otherwise since you would have to know the keys ahead of time anyway..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it does as it is a function specifically designed to be used to retrieve the value of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

**mysql_insert_id**

`Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).`

This type of thing is easy enough to test - have you tried it to see what happens?